# Nhibernate config mapping file

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have a web project and use nhibernate config file like this:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=afemanager;Integrated Security=no;User=sa;Password=password;</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping file="afe-serialization.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping file="afe-view.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
```

Then, I read the config like this:

```
 public static ISession GetSession()
 {
      NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();       
      return config.Configure(Path.Combine( HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath( "/" ), "App_Data", NHIBERNATE_CFG)).BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();
 }
```

When it runs, it's display exception:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Could not find file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\11.0\afe-serialization.hbm.xml'.

My .hbm file is not located in that directory. My question is how to set mapping file to get the .hbm file from App_Data directory.

Something like this:

```
Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/"), "App_Data", "afe-serialization.hbm.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the "Build Action" property of the hbm.xml file to "Embedded Resources" so that it gets copied to your project working directory during deployment. You can do this using the property window. In this case your mapping file can be in any directory of your choosing.

And your code can be something like:

```
 public static ISession GetSession()
{
  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();       
  return config.AddAssembly("Assembly Name").BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
config.Configure();
```

without parameters it will load your default hibernate.hbm.xml from your bin folder.